# how to set new plot data for bar chart using core-plot?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-plot

I am new to objective-c and xcode. It would be very thankful if someone can point how to set new plot data for bar chart using core-plot.
 I need to set data like : 
 y-axis and x-axis : as (10,1), (5,2), (20,3), (15,4)
and the output should come as :

```
---------------------
30
25
20      #
15      # #
10  #   # #
5   # # # #

    1 2 3 4
---------------------
```

It would be great if someone can provide me the .m and .h file
Thanks in advance

Joshua

Answer (score 1):

Look at the programs in the examples folder in your Core Plot directory. All three CPTestApp programs (Mac, iPhone, and iPad) have bar plots.

Answer (score 0):

The function numberForPlot is where you define your datas you want to plot:

```
   -(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
    {

NSNumber *num = nil;
    if ( [plot isKindOfClass:[CPBarPlot class]] ) {
        switch ( fieldEnum ) {
            case CPBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
            num = (NSNumber *)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[*yourArray* objectAtIndex:index] floatValue]];
                break;
            case CPBarPlotFieldBarLength:
                num = (NSNumber *)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[*yourOtherArray* objectAtIndex:index] floatValue]];
                break;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

You just have to insert datas in your arrays.